# Video stream with mime type 'application/octet-stream' on site

Tags: video, video-streaming, flash

I've got video stream. The problem is that it got mime type `application/octet-stream` and I can't change it (server is not mine). I can watch it with VLC player for Windows, but I can't find flash player for it. According to VLC audio is `MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)` and video is `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (Planar 4:2:0 YUV)`. So the question is: how can I play it on website? If it's not possible directly, what can I do to force the player play it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue for which I just asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503369/playing-video-of-type-application-octect-stream. I am using mediaelementplayer which somehow plays the video but with only audio. The screen goes black for some reason.